# FieldOperator class does not contain static Constants

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to use a FieldOperator in a Broker Query to select component presentations based on a date in the metadata. For this I use a CustomMetaValueCriteria.

```cs
CustomMetaValueCriteria yearCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(
  new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("sort_date"), 
  new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(NewsYear), 12, 31), 
  FieldOperator.LESS_OR_EQUAL_THAN);
```

It seems the static constants like LESS_OR_EQUAL_THAN, GREATER_OR_EQUAL_THAN and LIKE are not publically available. I'm using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.
Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Hi Wouter -Congrats on your first SDL Tridion related post on Stack Overflow. You may be interested in committing to the Area 51 proposal (it looks like you already have a log in there) at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 to help us get a dedicated SDL Tridion Q&A area. Thanks in advance. Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field operators are available as static properties of the Criteria class.
E.g.:

```
Criteria.GreaterThan
Criteria.Equal
```

etc.